# R Studio package installation problems: clang version doesn't match?

Tags: r, clang, install.packages

I'm on a Mac OS Sierra WITHOUT admin privileges (ugh). There's a bunch of packages I really need to install, but for the vast majority, when I try to install, I get the following error:

```
make: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang: No such file or directory
make: *** [base64.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RCurl’
```

I have clang installed but it's a different version:

```
clang --version
clang version 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
```

I suspect this mismatch is the problem, but not being particularly savvy with installs and the innards of the computer, I really have no idea how to resolve it. I haven't been able to find a similar enough issue that someone else that that's helped my situation.

I've tried editing my path to include all the possibilities that occur to me. I've also tried installing devtools (same error, essentially). My sessionInfo() and r --version information are below.

```
r --version
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28) -- "Short Summer"
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under the terms of the
GNU General Public License versions 2 or 3.
For more information about these matters see
http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
```

... and sessionInfo():

```
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.2 tools_3.4.2
```

Comment: Darwin 13.4.0 is Mavericks (macOS 10.9.x).   The current R release is built for El Capitan (10.11.x) or higher.  You should update to the current release if you can, or ask an admin to do it for you.

Comment: See the https://r.research.att.com/man/RMacOSX-FAQ.html#Installation-of-source-packages  (or) Mac OS X - Development Tools and Libraries - CRAN.R-project.org
https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/